# How do i prevent my pyqt program from freezing when fetching data?

Tags: python, qthread

my program tests my internet speed using the "speedtest" module i downloaded from pypi. It works as intended but the problem am facing is that the GUI freezes until everything has been collected and displays it instead of showing results one by one. Here is my code for the program

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4. QtCore import SIGNAL
import Speed2
import sys
import speedtest

class Speed(QtGui.QDialog, Speed2.Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.waitingSlot.setText('Testing your internet speed......................')

        try:
            speed = speedtest.Speedtest()
            details = speed.config
            self.providerSlot.setText('%(isp)s ' %details ['client'])
            #server
            self.waitingSlot.setText('Selecting best server based on ping......................')
            speed.get_best_server()
            #host
            host =  speed.get_best_server()
            self.serverSlot.setText('%(sponsor)s (%(name)s) [%(d)0.2f km] '%host)
            #ping
            self.pingSpeed.setText('%(latency)d' % host)
            #download
            self.waitingSlot.setText('Testing your download speed')
            download  = speed.download()
            down  = (download / 1000.0 /1000.0)
            if down > 99:
                downlink  = round(down, 1)
                self.downLink.setText(str(downlink))
            else:
                downlink = round(down, 2)
                self.downLoad.setText(str(downlink))
            #upload
            self.waitingSlot.setText('Testing your upload speed......................')
            upload = speed.upload()
            up  = (upload / 1000.0/ 1000.0)
            if up > 99:
                uplink = round(up, 1)
                sellf.upLoad.setText(str(uplink))
            else:
                uplink = round(up, 2)
                self.upLoad.setText(str(uplink))            
            self.waitingSlot.setText('Testing complete!!!!')

        except:
            self.waitingSlot.setText('Error in network connection') 


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Speed()
    gui.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You can only do this if `speedtest` provides a method for streaming the download/upload speeds.